# Creating APEX Trigger in Sandbox, works in Sandbox but wont deploy in Production

Tags: apex, trigger, community, files, digital-experience

I am trying to get an APEX Trigger from the sandbox into production for my org.  The trigger is to make all of the files that are uploaded into a record to show for the Community Partner users on the Digital Experience site.  I found a code that does work and I have tried it out in the Sandbox side of things, but when I try to deploy it, it says that there is 0% code coverage.  I don't know what this means, because I am not very knowledgeable about APEX coding.  I am starting to do more of this coding in the future, but I do need to have this functionality in our Production org.  I keep seeing on how I have to create a test class, but I don't know how to do that with this certain code.  Any help would be amazing, as I am about to pull out the rest of my hair that I already can't afford to lose.

```
trigger All_Users on ContentDocumentLink (before insert) {

//This trigger will make all new inserted files visible to Community Users
for(ContentDocumentLink l:Trigger.new) {
    l.Visibility='AllUsers';
}}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take the time to research apex and Salesforce in general. There are lots of resources available, not least here but also places like trailhead.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the suggestion.  I am actually a Certified Admin with Salesforce.  I have been doing research constantly for this issue and I keep ending up with vague answers or not the correct answers.  We have an Org that needs this functionality and I was hoping to find some guidance for such small code.

Comment: You need to write unit tests that exercise this code so you can promote it to production. Salesforce requires a minimum of 75% coverage. I have referenced a canonical answer that discusses how to write unit tests to get coverage. You could also follow the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro).